# pressing a button for X seconds?

Tags: c#

I've tried

```
keybd_event(keyByte, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);

Thread.Sleep(3000);

keybd_event(keyByte, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

But it only presses it once and pauses, I want it to simulate holding a button. Example if I'm simulating player two in a car game I've made and it wants to turn the car while moving forward. The curve is 90 so i then want to hold it for 3 seconds. How to i do this?

EDIT: tried

```
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan timespan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

                if (timespan.TotalMilliseconds < duration)
                {
                    timespan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);

                    keybd_event(keyByte, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
                }

                keybd_event(keyByte, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

but without result

Comment: you need timer which fires after 3000ms and sends key up event instead of sleep.

Comment: In the example you gave, why not just call the turning code directly? `start_turning; wait; stop_turning`

Comment: You need to add an alternative method of controlling a simulated player than relying on keyboard input. Your game engine shouldn't care HOW the car is being controlled, an 'controller' layer should receive keyboard input or automated commands, and pass the appropriate instruction to the game engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set a timer for 3 seconds and when it fires, you should release the button.

Comment: +1: But please include the reason why (iow using `Thread.Sleep` will block the windows message loop).

Comment: some sample code too, look at my edit, its a loop but does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

You could call it every update, this would simulate each update checking for input and finding it. It should also cause minimal change if you want to give the option between manual control and computer control.

But as far as I'm aware there is no option to say "generate this input until I say otherwise".

Also as a note, if you are trying to move a car on a track (say in a game) there is math for that, you generally simulate the user's controls using that instead of just having the computer press the button.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try putting

keybd_event(keyByte, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);

in a loop for 3 seconds?

Comment: Ive tried: const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
                    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = 0x0;

                    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                    TimeSpan timespan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

                    if (timespan.TotalMilliseconds < duration)
                    {
                        timespan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start);

                        keybd_event(keyByte, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0);
                    }

                    keybd_event(keyByte, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0); without result :(

Comment: @Jason94 That code would process KEYUP at every loop, you should have an else in there so it only fires when the duration is exceeded.